# Не отображается baloon в react-yandex-map

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Всем привет. Использую react-yandex-map в приложении на NextJS. Использую ObjectManager, т.к. > 5000 объектов. В документации ничего нету по его использованию. Изучал типы, исходники, безрезультатно. Нашел пару примеров в интернетах, но там тоже не показывается baloon. Изучал основную документацию, пробовал в примеры подставлять разные поля, пробовал менять структуру объекта данных (брал из оф доки и подставлял в пример) - результат 0. Может кто сталкивался, 3й день мучаюсь).
[Ссылка на ресурс с примером.](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-fast-ufbcij?file=/src/index.js) Как я понял, это пример автора самой библиотеки.

Answer (score 1):

Мало ли кому пригодится.

```
modules={[
    'objectManager.addon.objectsBalloon',
    'objectManager.addon.objectsHint',
]}
```

Comment: Не забудьте отметить ваш ответ "галочкой" :)